# Reset state proces if I back to first step

Tags: user-expectation, status, multi-step, flow

I’m thinking about resetting the state after back to init step in the process.

For example - In the project, I have two creators to build the automations (if->then condidtion type). In the first step, I can choose a type of creator, in the second step I can configure the automation. If I click “back” on the 2 step I get the init state (without configure the automation). Some people expect that the automation will be in memory if they go to step two again. I’m not sure.

[image]

Comment: Yes, users assume that their inputs are saved throughout a wizard. What is your question exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the correct approach. If a user has two separate builders (with two different input data) and the user return from step 2 to step 1 (to change builder type) and then go to again to step 2a should have input data in memory. I consider resetting the process in the builder.

Answer (score 1):

If the type changes and the old input still works, the application should ask whether to preserve it or not.

If the type changes and the old input doesn't suit the new type anymore, the application should notify the user that the old input won't work with the new type that is about to be set. An option to cancel type changing should be given as well of course.